# How to save model.summary() to file in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, stdout

There is [model.summary() method](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/) in Keras. It prints table to stdout. Is it possible to save this to file?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you want the formatting of summary you can pass a `print` function to `model.summary()` and output to file that way:

```
def myprint(s):
    with open('modelsummary.txt','a') as f:
        print(s, file=f)

model.summary(print_fn=myprint)
```

Alternatively, you can serialize it to a json or yaml string with `model.to_json()` or `model.to_yaml()` which can be imported back later.

### Edit

An more pythonic way to do this in Python 3.4+ is to use `contextlib.redirect_stdout`

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('modelsummary.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        model.summary()
```

Comment: model.to_json() looks like better to retrieve information in the future, once that is a semi-structured data

Comment: 'w+' should be replaced with 'a', because model.summary writes several times.

Answer (score 16):

Here you have another option:

```
with open('modelsummary.txt', 'w') as f:

    model.summary(print_fn=lambda x: f.write(x + '\n'))
```

Comment: This is neat and utterly Pythonic.

Comment: The advantage of using `redirect_stdout` is that it works for anything that produces output on stdout, so no need for library developers to add `print_fn` options as has been done here in Keras.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more succinct and pythonic:

```
with open('model.summary', 'w') as sys.stdout:
  model.summary()

# ...reset 'sys.stdout' for later script output
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```